# Ubuntu 12.04 Wifi/Brightness Fn Keys don't work

Tags: wireless, brightness, toshiba, function-keys

I have scoured the Internet trying to find a solution to my problem.

I have a Toshiba L755D-S5171 and like many people the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key works to a very small extent.

The <kbd>Fn</kbd>+3/4 works to vol-down/up and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> works to mute like many have reported.

I have looked for that "BIOS option" some users speak of, and there isn't one for my model.  I have installed **Fnfxd** and **fnfx** and all that Jazz but no cigar.

Like one user I noticed recently my <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>/<kbd>F7</kbd> keys "work" after a suspend (they show brightness bar and it changes, but no real change to brightness) and i can softblock my WiFi, all after a suspension, but they still do not actually work as designed.

I don't know if there is an answer out there, but if there is I would like to be told or pointed to it.

I really like Ubuntu and would like to use it on a regular basis for everything but gaming, but if i cannot change power consumption options on the fly then Windows will work better for me.

I see alot of posts/threads asking for help, and only a few replies that work for a few people.

All I really need to work is the WiFi, I do a lot of stuff online, and a lot of stuff offline, and if I am traveling I don't want to have to restart my computer to turn off WiFi in the BIOS.

- Toshiba L755D-S5171 650Gb
- HDD = 70Gb Ubuntu 12.04 AMD64, 580Gb Windows 7 Home Premium x64
- AMD Llano A6 3420 1.5Ghz Quad core
- 4GB 1333 DDR3 204pin RAM

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal (<kbd>Clt</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and run the command given below:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Now the new window opens and you will see the lines given below:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite_splice"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

Now you have to change the lines above by the command lines given below:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Then save the window and Update the grub from the terminal using:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now you can increase or decrease the brightness in PC with Latest Ubuntu in it.

Enjoy!

---

[Source - Blog](http://thehtd.blogspot.com/2012/08/brightness-problem-in-ubuntu-1204.html)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't change graphics with Fn keys on my Acer laptop.

This helped me, added to /etc/default/grub:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force
>   acpi_backlight=vendor"

Then runupdate-grub and reboot.

Source: http://www.refreshit.info/2012/08/solved-brightness-increase-and-decrease.html