# My laptop brightness doesnot be darker with function key

Tags: brightness, function-keys

My laptop has intel hd graphics 4400, and it doesn't work well on ubuntu 14.04 , so I upgraded to ubuntu 15.04.

It works fine, but i cannot change my brightness.

The funny thing is that i can change the brightness by terminal command or at the system setting.

The max brightness value is 937, so i can edit the brightness to 300, 500 or other values by terminal command. Also I can change it brighter by function key.

But I cannot make it darker by function key!

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Brightness wont change](http://askubuntu.com/questions/493693/brightness-wont-change)

Comment: And what is your laptop model?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open a terminal
2. Run `pkexec gedit /etc/default/grub`
3. Type your password and the text editor will open. Find the line containing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`
4. Change it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"`.
5. Save the file and close the text editor.
6. In the terminal, now type `sudo update-grub`.
7. Reboot, and see if it works.

Source: [Brightness function keys not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266046/brightness-function-keys-not-working/266056#266056) and [Ubuntu 12.04 Wifi/Brightness Fn Keys don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196282/ubuntu-12-04-wifi-brightness-fn-keys-dont-work/263564#263564) and http://thehtd.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/brightness-problem-in-ubuntu-1204.html

By the way, it would be helpful if you could specify what laptop you're using.

Comment: This is not needed if brightness can be controlled.

Comment: @Pilot6 what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that editing grub config is not needed in this case.

Comment: I've seen this answer in multiple locations, and it seemed to work for most people. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, this answer works in many cases, but this is not that case.

Comment: I've already tried that, but it didn't work